# customizing a drawable for a range of APIs Android

Tags: android, customization, drawable

I'd like to customize one drawable e.g.
/drawable/image.png

only for APis 19 to 21. For later APIs (after 22 incl. I'd like a drawable to be different). Do I need to create directories
drawable-v19, 
drawable-v20, 
drawable-v21, 
drawable-v22 (for the others?)
? It's a bit unclear to me how it works...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should only need to create directories for the versions that set a different resource. So your resources directory would look something like:

```
res/
    drawable/        --> SDK version below 19
        image.png
    drawable-v19/    --> SDK version between 19 and 21 (including both)
        image.png
    drawable-v22/    --> SDK version 22 and greater
        image.png
```

**Edit:** Seems to be working this way. I've set up a small project with strings.xml for sdk 19 and 22, launched two emulators, with sdk 21 and 25. The SDK 21 one showed the string in the v19 strings, and the SDK 25 the one in v22 strings. Here's a pic with the results:[image: Andoroir version qualifires]

Hope it helps. (Couldn't test it with sdk lower than 19, but that should take values from the default file, since no qualifier applies.)

Comment: thx for the answer, according to user2695433 (see above) the /drawable folder will work for all the others, and according to your answer drawable-v2 2 will work for 22 and greater. So there's something wrong. Where do 23 devices fall in this case? into /drawable-v22 or /drawable?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) each version qualifier serves for its version and higher (from that page: `v4 for API level 4 (devices with Android 1.6 or higher)`), so you should only define the folders for the "inflexion points" sort to say. Haven't had the chance to test it yet, but will try it.

Comment: thanks , it is exactly my biggest worry in the whole question cause it can theoretically work both ways...

Comment: Right now I can't test it, only have a laptop with me and it's dying only to open android studio, don't want to imagine what will happen if I also open an emulator. First thing I'll do when reaching home is test this.

Comment: thx, will it work for styles.xml analogically or there's a different logic?

Comment: It will work the same way for every folder inside resources.

Comment: Test it and its working this way, see the edit. And sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can create drawable folders like drawable-v19, drawable-v20, drawable-v21, drawable-v22 for each custom images for each versions. If the app is running on one of these devices it picks from these matching version custom respective folders or else falls back to the generic drawable folder.

Comment: thx for the answer, please see my answer to the next post below

Comment: @hhg. thanks for pointing your concern. The specifically named folders will be matched according to the api versions and if not matching the fall back would be the drawable ( generic ) one. Not yet tested for v23 though, but v24 should fall in generic ( drawable).

Comment: thx, will it work for styles.xml analogically or there's a different logic?